# How to apply multiple Order by in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails application I have a table called **HealthcareCenter**.

I want to list HealthcareCenter based on below order(I have pagination, per page should list 50 records).

1. Number of recommentations (If user logged in)
2. Ratings (high rating first)
3. Distance (first set distance should be < 25km, second distance between 25 and 100, third any distance but ascending order)

I will explain by below image

[image]

At image we can see 5 clinics, as like shown in image sql should order the  clicnics

I have written

```
HealthcareCenter.where("healthcare_centers.name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%")
                        .where(type_id: type_id)
                        .order("healthcare_centers.overall_rating DESC")
                        .calculate_distance2a(lat, lon)                 
                        .order("distance")
                        .order("healthcare_centers.name")
                        .offset(offset)
                        .limit(limit)

def self.calculate_distance2a(orig_lat, orig_lon, dist = nil)
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = the_square(orig_lat, orig_lon, dist)
    self.select(" healthcare_centers.id,
      ROUND(
        6371 * 2 * ASIN ( SQRT (
          POWER( SIN((#{orig_lat} - healthcare_centers.latitude)*pi()/180 / 2),2)
          + COS(#{orig_lat} * pi()/180)
          * COS(healthcare_centers.latitude *pi()/180)
          * POWER(SIN((#{orig_lon} - healthcare_centers.longitude) *pi()/180 / 2), 2)
    ) ),2) as distance"
    )
    .where("healthcare_centers.longitude between #{lon1} and #{lon2}")
    .where("healthcare_centers.latitude  between #{lat1} and #{lat2}")
    .order("distance")
end
```

This query give me the list of clinics with high rating (because currenly I am checking user not logged in) but gives me greater than 25KM as first result

Because on my DB more than 25KM have high rating

Can you please guide me on how to include those distance condition

1) <= 25

2) > 25 && <= 100

3) > 100 (should be in asc order)

Consider If less than 25KM we have 2 Clicnics.Clinic A 4.3(rating), 2Km distance, Clinic B 3(rating), 1.5km based on rating Clinic A should list on top.

Comment: I think ordering by distance first and then rating should do the trick.. `.order('distance asc, healthcare_centers.overall_rating desc')`

Comment: Consider If less than 25KM we have 2 Clicnics.Clinic A 4.3(rating), 2Km distance, Clinic B 3(rating), 1.5km based on rating Clinic A should list on top but If I sort by distance and rating clinic B come as first. That is wrong @Md. Farhan Memon

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate distance as a column alias  an then

```
HealthcareCenter.where("healthcare_centers.name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%")
                    .where(type_id: type_id)
                    .order("healthcare_centers.overall_rating DESC,
                          distance,
                          healthcare_centers.name")
```

Comment: sorry can you please explain bit more

Comment: how to include that distance value condition on distance as a column alias

Comment: in your select  you should create a calculated  column with name distance